# select date from jdatechooser and automatically diplay age in a Textfield

Tags: java, jtextfield, netbeans-8, jdatechooser

i'm trying to get the selected date from Jdatechooser and display the age corresponding to the date in a Textfield, i saw all the threads discussing this problem but it doesn"t work for me.here is my code:

```
 private void datenaiss_choozPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                               
    Date date = (Date) datenaiss_chooz.getDate(); 
LocalDate ld = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
Period p =Period.between(ld, LocalDate.now());
age.setText(p);


}
```

Comment: What exactly you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Can you share the output you got so far? May be you just need to do `p. getYears()`, `p. getMonths()` etc.

Comment: i wrote age.setText(p.getyears) and i got "incompatible types:it can not be converted to string"

Comment: `getYears()` returns `int` and you need to place a `String` type in text field. So use `String.valueOf(p.getYears());`

Comment: age.setText(String.valueOf(p.getYears()));  not working unfortunately :/

Comment: Any error or observations to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after long hours i got the solution, thanks everybody for helping me.Here is my code that works perfectly  :

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(datenaiss_chooz.getDate());
Years h = Years.yearsBetween(start, new DateTime()); 
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append(h.getYears());
String str = b.toString();
if ( h.getYears()==0)
age.setText(""); 
else
age.setText(str+" "+"ans");
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem using joda-time :

```
DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime now = new DateTime();
Period period = new Period(birthDate, now);
int years = period.getYears();
System.out.println(years);
```

This will give you the difference you required !

Comment: it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: What are you looking for then ?

Comment: bravo ! nice to hear it !